# Laravel, slow static content serving on localhost/windows

Tags: php, windows, laravel, localhost, laravel-artisan

I'm developing laravel appliaction on windows enviroment (artisan) and I'm having some non-criticial but annoying speed issues.
First of all, I'm not talking about DB access, speed is issue with serving static content and maybe not related to laravel:

- I start with `php artisans serve`
- Then open app in browser some static content http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/script.js
- It serves tiny javascript file and takes 204ms(!)
- When I publish same file on (shared) hosting enviroment, it takes < 45ms.

I belive it is related to windows environment but don't know how to speed up a little bit. Same situation is with any static content and when I execute this as whole app (http://127.0.0.1:8000/) it takes few seconds to execute something very basic.

I have decent computer (win8.1, 64bit, i5, 3.4Gh, SSD disk).

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question, perhaps you can find help at [sf]. Generally, development web servers are not optimized for speed but development convenience.

Answer (score -2):

I think `php artisan serve` doesn't effect loading speed. If you want to test it, then you can also access project by not using this command. Instead directly access it by

```
http://localhost/your-project-folder/public
```

hope it will help you.

Comment: When I do it this way (through XAMPP, http://127.0.0.1/app_name/public/js/script.js), it takes 3ms, so I belive that artisan add some impact on speed.

Comment: @Moebius XAMPP uses apache, artisan the built-in PHP development server. Completely different things.

Comment: @Moebius Did you tried my solution? and test speed?

Comment: @Maitray Suthar, yes, as I mentioned, it takes <= 3ms, but I'm looking for "artisan serve" way.

Comment: @pvg, I understand that. I used XAMPP just to test Suthar solution. I looks like PHP development server (called via artisan) process it slow.